# Clearing a MongoDB on Heroku

Tags: database, mongodb, heroku, meteor

I want to delete all the values in my MONGODB database. My app is running on Heroku, it is a MeteorJS application.

I have figured out how to create a button to delete one entry, and it is as follows, but I'm not sure how to make a button to delete all entries. Also, is there any command I can run on the command line to clear it? On my local server I simply run METEOR RESET, but how to do it for my heroku app? Thanks!

```
Template.druglist.helpers({
  druglist() {

    return Drugs.find().fetch();
  },
  drugdelete() {
    Drugs.remove(this._id);
    M.toast({ html: this.Product_Name + " has been removed." });
  }
});
Template.druglist.events({

  "click .drugdelete": function (e, tmpl) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure? This record will be removed permanently.")) {
      return false;
    }
    var x = Template.druglist.__helpers.get('drugdelete').call(this);

  }
});

<button class="waves-effect red btn drugdelete" dataatr={{_id}}">Delete</button>
```

Edit: I have found that I can delete a collection on MLAB itself, but how do I delete it with code on my app?